# Read only field from related model not appearing, with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models (and an abstract model): User, Mage and Character. Mage 'inherits' from Character.

Character has an `updated_date` field, and I'm trying to pull through the latest date that a User's Mage was updated:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mage_by_user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Mage.objects.all())
    mage_last_updated = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='mage_by_user.updated_date')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'mage_by_user', 'mage_last_updated',)
```

But for some reason the `'mage_last_updated'` field just does not appear! If I delete `'mage_by_user'` then it errors, complaining that the `'mage_last_updated'` field needs it to exist. So somewhere it recognises it.

How do I troubleshoot this? How do I fix it?

---

## Edit:

Here is the json with a few edits, for the sake of this question (namely, I've inserted the mage object, to show the updated_date field)

```
{
    "id":1,
    "username":"admin",
    "mage_by_user":[{
        "id":3,
        "player":"admin",
        "name":"gandalf",
        "sub_race":"Foo",
        "faction":"Foo",
        "is_published":false,
        "updated_date":"2015-02-11T16:13:16.229890Z",
        "power_level":1,
        "energy_trait":7,
        "virtue":"prudence",
        "vice":"lust",
        "morality":7,
        "size":5,
        "arcana":{
            "Matter":0,
            "Death":0,
            "Fate":1,
            "Mind":0,
            "Prime":0,
            "Forces":0,
            "Spirit":0,
            "Time":0,
            "Space":0,
            "Life":0
        },            
        "mental_attributes":{
            "Wits":0,
            "Intelligence":1,
            "Resolve":0
        },
        "physical_attributes":{
            "Dexterity":0,
            "Stamina":0,
            "Strength":0
        },
        social_attributes":{
            "Composure":0,
            "Presence":0,
            "Manipulation":0
        },
        "mental_skills":{
            "Politics":0,
            "Academics":1,
            "Crafts":0,
            "Medicine":0,
            "Occult":0,
            "Science":0,
            "Investigation":0,
            "Computer":0
        },
        "physical_skills":{
            "Survival":0,
            "Athletics":0,
            "Weaponry":0,
            "Stealth":0,
            "Larceny":0,
            "Brawl":0,
            "Drive":0,
            "Firearms":0
        },
        "social_skills":{
            "Subterfuge":0,
            "Expression":0,
            "Socialize":0,
            "Streetwise":0,
            "Animal Ken":0,
            "Persuasion":0,
            "Empathy":0,
            "Intimidation":0
        }
    }]
}
```

Also, adding `many=True` is not correct for the read only field `mage_last_updated`, as Django complains. Here `mage_by_user` is the list of mages 'owned' by the user.

Comment: Shouldn't the `mage_last_updated` have `many=True` since your are getting a list of `mage_by_user`?

Comment: @SamRad I only really want the latest mages date, not all of them. It still doesn't explain why it just doesn't exist.

Comment: Would you post an example of your output/models? Does any `mage_by_user` have `updated_date` field?

Comment: @Samrad I'll double check tomorrow,  but they should all have one as its an auto field.  I'm on my phone but here is a question with an output : http://stackoverflow.com/q/28700626/1075247

Comment: @SamRad Does my edit help?

Comment: As I said you are getting a list of `Mage`s. Each `Mage` has an `updated_date` field but you only want the latest one. How is django supposed to guess which `updated_date` you are asking? I'm still confused. Do you want the latest Mage with its `updated_date` field or you want all of the Mages but you want to include the  latest `updated_date` to the response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71655/discussion-between-pureferret-and-sam-rad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussion we had in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71655/discussion-between-pureferret-and-sam-rad):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mage_by_user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Mage.objects.all())
    mage_last_updated = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'mage_by_user', 'mage_last_updated',)

    def get_mage_last_updated(self, obj):
        latest_mage = obj.mage_set.latest('updated_date')
        return latest_mage.updated_date
```