# Why do I get loose closing brackets for my Django Rest Framework endpoint?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, typeerror

Here's my JSON response for `http://localhost:8000/characters/api/users/1?format=json`

```
)]}',
{"id":1,"username":"admin","mage_by_user":[3],"mage_last_updated":"2015-02-11T16:13:16.229Z"}
```

Notice the `)]}',` on the first line.

Here is my code that gets called to create the JSON:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mage_by_user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Mage.objects.all())
    mage_last_updated = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='mage_by_user.updated_date')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'mage_by_user', 'mage_last_updated',)
```

---

Further testing:

- I've noticed the title of the page is `TypeError at <insert url here>`.
- This happens with all of my endpoints
- If I try to access a non-existent object (userId=2 for instance), then renders 'normally' for DRF, e.g:

  {
     detail: "Not found"
  }

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Have you tried making a call to the API using requests? 
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

If you are still getting the brackets there, then it's your code. If not, it's the browser doing some strange things.

Comment: @GooseNinja see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28717667/1075247

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those characters are inserted by the Djangular middleware [`AngularJsonVulnerabilityMiddleware`](https://github.com/appliedsec/djangular#enabling-csrf-protection-in-angularjs-templates), to inject [Json Vulnerability Protection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#json-vulnerability-protection)

> A JSON vulnerability allows third party website to turn your JSON resource URL into JSONP request under some conditions. To counter this your server can prefix all JSON requests with following string `")]}',\n"`. Angular will automatically strip the prefix before processing it as JSON.

Unfortunately, it means it breaks various JSON viewers.

Comment: The Angular JS motivation there is completely muddled and unjustified. They link to a report in 2008 that does not mention JSONP, and *isn't* actually about JSONP at all.

Comment: @TomChristie so does that 'protection' not work? Is it pointless?

Comment: @TomChristie actually it is about JSONP but it's not called as such, it still involves padding a JSON from `friendly.com` by `evil.co.uk` (English are always the baddies) to *make* the JSONP. Right? Even so, they seem to do it in a stupid way, not the way the article recommends.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to not be more help, but this looks like something entirely unrelated to REST framework. There's absolutely no way a JSON response there would ever be rendered in that way.

Perhaps you have a custom renderer configured, that's outputting a malformed response, perhaps you have some broken middleware inserting those characters, perhaps its an issue in the client or whatever environment you're making the requests, or perhaps it's something else entirely unrelated to any of those.

I'd start by trying to narrow down the issue as much as possible - remove all the complexity from the view and serializer and attempt to replicate the behavior in a test case.

Most likely there's some sort of unexpected integration issue you're missing or some otherwise obvious code typo that's being overlooked.

Comment: Thanks Tom,  I appreciate you looking into this. I'll get on looking at the things you mentioned.

Comment: Found it. It's part of the Djangular middleware to protect against JSON vulnerabilities.